# Wait for all nested Futures to complete

Tags: scala, future

```
val works: Seq[Future[Seq[Future[String]]]] = ...
```

How would I wait for all these top and nested `Futures` to complete?

My first idea is:

```
val result1: Seq[Seq[Future[String]]] = Await.result(
  Future.sequence(works), Duration.Inf
)

val result2: Seq[String] =  Await.result(
  Future.sequence(result1.flatten), Duration.Inf
)
```

But I guess it is not as effiecient as it could be.

Comment: How does one end up with `Seq[Future[Seq[Future[String]]]]` in the first place?

Comment: @m-z https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/NestedFutures.scala

Comment: Yeah, although it's a good idea to nest algebraic data structures and match them recursively, but future isn't ADT. You would better flatten them as soon as you can

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't nest multiple `Futures`, normally you would use `map`, `flatMap`, for comprehensions, ... to chain asynchronous operations using `Futures` together.

If you want to continue with your `Seq[Future[Seq[Future[String]]]]`, you can use the `Future.sequence` and `Seq.flatten` functions you were using to create a `Future[Seq[String]]` :

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val works = Seq(Future.successful(Seq(Future.successful("abc"))))

val onlyOneFuture: Future[Seq[String]] = 
  Future.sequence(works).map(_.flatten).flatMap(Future.sequence(_))

Await.result(onlyOneFuture, 5.seconds)
// Seq[String] = List(abc)
```